How to dynamically set VCPKG_FORCE_SYSTEM_BINARIES (based on architecture) in a DevContainer configuration?
I'm working on a DevContainer configuration and need to dynamically set the VCPKG_FORCE_SYSTEM_BINARIES environment variable based on the detected architecture (e.g., 0 for x86_64, 1 for other architectures like arm64).
Here is my current devcontainer.json:
{
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "dockerfile-ubuntu",
        "args": {
            "VCPKG_FORCE_SYSTEM_BINARIES": "1"
        }
    }
}

Currently, VCPKG_FORCE_SYSTEM_BINARIES is statically set to 1 via the build argument. I want to make this dynamic so that its value is determined based on the architecture ($containerArchitecture) during the build or runtime of the DevContainer.
I’ve tried various approaches but am unsure how to conditionally set the value for VCPKG_FORCE_SYSTEM_BINARIES depending on the architecture.
Is there a way to evaluate the architecture and set the build argument or environment variable dynamically?
How can I integrate such logic into the devcontainer.json or Dockerfile?
I hesitate to mess up with the CMakePresets to accomplish this.
Any suggestions or best practices for this scenario would be greatly appreciated!
